# Oracle datareader does not return any row

Tags: c#

When i run the following sql statement in sql developer it will return 2 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST
```

When i run the following code on the same connenction, the datareader.HasRows will be false:

```
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = Connection;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TEST";
        OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(dr.GetString(1));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("no found rows");
        }
```

Why does the datareader not contains any rows?

Additional information:

- Oracle 11g XE 64 bit installed.
- Installed ODAC 11.2 64 bit.
- Added reference to "oracle\odp.net\bin\4\Oracle.DataAccess.dll"
- Added: using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;

Comment: `connection` should be open ?

Comment: Are you sure the table contains any records? Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: Try change "Test" table to "Dual". If `datareader.HasRows` becomes `true` "Test" is empty, if not (i.e. still `false`) check the connection

Comment: The connection is open and i am not getting any exceptions.

Comment: Side note: wrap `IDisposable` instances like `OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand()`, `OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()` into *using*

Comment: Using dual indeed gives a true! However i am surely that my TEST table is not empty. How else should sql developer return 2 rows?

Comment: Are you sure the login (user id/password) your using in your code is pointing to where you think it is?  You can also add the schema just to make sure: select * from <schema>.TEST

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because i did not commited my create table and insert statements, the data was not avaible for 3rd party components.

Comment: Spended several hours to find a solution! It helps!

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick for me. :)

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day.